# Selenium WindowHandles not detect all opened popups

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to switch between two opened Popups. But `driver.WindowHandles` return only 1 handle(ID). I don't know how to switch to second popup.
Command `driver.SwitchTo().ActiveElement` doesn't work.

```
ReadOnlyCollection<string> currentHandlesList = driver.WindowHandles;
Console.WriteLine(currentHandlesList.Count);
```

Result of this : 1

Why it returns 1. Why not 2 ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should use below approach :-

```
string currentHandle = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
//Save the currently-focused window handle into a variable so that you can switch back to it later.

ReadOnlyCollection<string> originalHandles = driver.WindowHandles;
//Get the list of currently opened window handles.

// Now work here to open popups

// WebDriverWait.Until<T> waits until the delegate return the popup window handle.
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

string popupWindowHandle = wait.Until<string>((d) =>
{
    string foundHandle = null;

    // Subtract out the list of known handles. In the case of a single
    // popup, the newHandles list will only have one value.
    List<string> newHandles = driver.CurrentWindowHandles.Except(originalHandles).ToList();
    if (newHandles.Count > 0)
    {
        foundHandle = newHandles[0];
    }

    return foundHandle;
});

driver.SwitchTo().Window(popupWindowHandle);

// Do whatever you need to on the popup browser, then...
driver.Close();
driver.SwitchToWindow(currentHandle);
```

In this way you can work with popups.. hope it will help you..:)